# Http 401 error when posting to GoogleGroups API in Java?

Tags: java, api, google-groups

The documentation on the Google API site does not include any complete working examples on using the groups api to access or modify a group, such as adding a member.  There are snippets for different parts, but I am getting a 401 error when I put it all together and I have no idea if I am leaving out some key part.

I have tried putting the snippets I have found together into a working application, but am getting a 401 error.

```
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("<path to my json file I downloaded from the service accounts page>"))
                .createScoped(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group"));

        URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/<identifier to the group, such as the group email address>/members");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + credential.getAccessToken());
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        StringBuffer jsonParamsBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        jsonParamsBuffer    .append("{")
                .append("\"email\": \"")
                .append("test-email@notarealdomain.fake")
                .append("\", ")
                .append("\"role\": \"")
                .append("MEMBER")
                .append("\"")
                .append("}")
                .append("]")
                .append("}");

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(jsonParamsBuffer.toString().getBytes());
        os.flush();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Response from Google Groups APi:");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();
```

Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups//members

Comment: To eliminate several errors: which group are you posting to? Are you using admin credentials for that group? Can you call the API using curl? Do you get an error message back in the http response?

Comment: credential.getAccessToken() is coming back with null, so obviously that's at least part of the problem.

Comment: Token was expired, even though it was brand new.  Adding a call to .refreshToken() fixed that part, but now I'm getting a 400 response from the POST.

Comment: JSON was poorly formed.  After fixing that, I am getting a 403.

Comment: Update the question with the new information, also my questions from my first comment are still valid.